# Page gets cut in the half if I print from Chrome or Google Cloud but with Firefox doesn't

Tags: chrome, cups, troubleshooting, google-cloud

I'm setting up print server for custom thermal printer on RaspberryPi running Linux Debian and I have a strange problem. If I print a test page it prints OK, same with web page from Firefox, but when I try print from Google Chrome or Google Cloud Printing (I set up cloud printing server), half of page is cut, like there's wrong width defined.

In PDF viewer when I just click 'Print' it prints in wrong format, but when I enter in printer properties (just enter and close, no changes!) it prints OK.

I made `PPD` file for this printer manually, but it looks OK compared to other `PPD`s.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
 If I'm printing from safari on iOS google page is scaled properly, but others aren't.

Here's my PPD file:

```
*PPD-Adobe: "4.3"
*%%%% PPD file for Label Printer with CUPS.
*%%%% Created by the CUPS PPD Compiler CUPS v1.5.3.
*% Copyright 2007-2011 by Apple Inc.
*% Copyright 1997-2007 by Easy Software Products.
*% 
*% These coded instructions, statements, and computer programs are the
*% property of Apple Inc. and are protected by Federal copyright
*% law.  Distribution and use rights are outlined in the file "LICENSE.txt"
*% which should have been included with this file.  If this file is
*% file is missing or damaged, see the license at "http://www.cups.org/".
*FormatVersion: "4.3"
*FileVersion: "1.5"
*LanguageVersion: English
*LanguageEncoding: ISOLatin1
*PCFileName: "mefa2012-4.ppd"
*Product: "Mefa 2012-4"
*Manufacturer: "Mefa"
*ModelName: "MEFA2012-2"
*ShortNickName: "MEFA2012-2"
*NickName: "Mefa 2012-4"
*PSVersion: "(3010.000) 0"
*LanguageLevel: "3"
*ColorDevice: False
*DefaultColorSpace: Gray
*FileSystem: False
*Throughput: "8"
*LandscapeOrientation: Plus90
*TTRasterizer: Type42
*% Driver-defined attributes...
*RequiresPageRegion All: True
*cupsVersion: 1.5
*cupsModelNumber: 0
*cupsManualCopies: False
*cupsFilter: "application/vnd.cups-raster 0 rastertolabel"
*cupsLanguages: "en"
*OpenUI *PageSize/Media Size: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *PageSize
*DefaultPageSize: Def
*PageSize Def/112 x 149 mm:"<</PageSize[318 421]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*PageSize w112h158/112 x 158 mm: "<</PageSize[318 448]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*PageSize w112h210/112 x 210 mm: "<</PageSize[318 596]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*PageSize w112h297/112 x 297 mm: "<</PageSize[318 843]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *PageSize
*OpenUI *PageRegion/Media Size: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *PageRegion
*DefaultPageRegion: Def
*PageRegion Def/112 x 149 mm: "<</PageSize[318 421]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*PageRegion w112h158/112 x 158 mm: "<</PageSize[318 448]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*PageRegion w112h210/112 x 210 mm: "<</PageSize[318 596]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*PageRegion w112h297/112 x 297 mm: "<</PageSize[318 843]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *PageRegion
*DefaultImageableArea: Def
*ImageableArea Def/112 x 149 mm: "11.3 0 306.1 421.3596"
*ImageableArea w112h158/112 x 158 mm: "11.3 0 306.1 448.315" 
*ImageableArea w112h210/112 x 210 mm: "11.3 0 306.1 595.862"
*ImageableArea w112h297/112 x 297 mm: "11.3 0 306.1 842.719"
*DefaultPaperDimension: Def
*PaperDimension Def/112 x 149 mm: "317 421"
*PaperDimension w112h158/112 x 158 mm: "317 448"
*PaperDimension w112h210/112 x 210 mm: "317 596"
*PaperDimension w112h297/112 x 297 mm: "317 843"
*MaxMediaWidth: "317"
*MaxMediaHeight: "843"
*HWMargins: 11 0 11 0
*OpenUI *Resolution/Resolution: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *Resolution
*DefaultResolution: 203dpi
*Resolution 203dpi/203dpi: "<</HWResolution[203 203]/cupsBitsPerColor 1/cupsRowCount 0/cupsRowFeed 0/cupsRowStep 0/cupsColorSpace 3>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *Resolution
*OpenUI *cupsDarkness/Darkness: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *cupsDarkness
*DefaultcupsDarkness: Normal
*cupsDarkness Light/Light: "<</cupsCompression 0>>setpagedevice"
*cupsDarkness Medium/Medium: "<</cupsCompression 1>>setpagedevice"
*cupsDarkness Normal/Normal: "<</cupsCompression 2>>setpagedevice"
*cupsDarkness Dark/Dark: "<</cupsCompression 3>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *cupsDarkness
*DefaultFont: Courier
*Font AvantGarde-Book: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font AvantGarde-BookOblique: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font AvantGarde-Demi: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font AvantGarde-DemiOblique: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-Demi: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-DemiItalic: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-Light: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-LightItalic: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier-Bold: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier-BoldOblique: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier-Oblique: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Bold: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-BoldOblique: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow-BoldOblique: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow-Oblique: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Oblique: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-Bold: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-BoldItalic: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-Italic: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-Roman: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-Bold: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-BoldItalic: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-Italic: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-Roman: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Symbol: Special "(001.005)" Special ROM
*Font Times-Bold: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-BoldItalic: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-Italic: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-Roman: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font ZapfChancery-MediumItalic: Standard "(1.05)" Standard ROM
*Font ZapfDingbats: Special "(001.005)" Special ROM
*% End of mefa2012-4.ppd, 07287 bytes.
```

Comment: Please post the PPD file, in case it's relevant.